# check if function was called before

Tags: c

Here is my basic code that I'm trying to work with.

```
void test(){
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("input.txt.", "r");
}
```

So I'm trying to check if file was already opened before, meaning that void test() function was called once before. I realy have no idea how to do that, i tried it with while and if.
Like this.

```
void test(){
    FILE *input;
    int open = 0;
    while (open == 0){
        input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
        if (input == NULL){
            printf("File wasnt opened.\n");
        }
        if (input != NULL){
            printf("File is opened.\n");
        }
        open = open + 1;
    }
    if(open!=0){
        printf("file is already opened.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `static int open = 0;`.

Comment: Was going to say the same 

Comment: Do you understand why that works? Read up on static variables.

Comment: Even if the function was called before, that does not mean you can still access the file. A local variable declared with `FILE *input;` does not generally retain its value between calls to the function. So, the first call to `test` may open the file and store the `FILE` pointer into `input`, but, if the second call tries to use `input` to access the file without opening the file again, it will likely fail, because `input` will not contain the `FILE` pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a local static variable.

```
void test (void)
{
  static bool called_before = false;

  if(called_before)
  {
    do_this();
  }
  else
  {
    do_that();
    called_before = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your intent is for `test` to open the file just once but to read from the file each time it is called, you can make `input` static:

```
void test(void)
{
    /*  Since input is static, it will be initialized with NULL when the
        program starts and we will retain its value between calls to
        the function.
    */
    static FILE *input = NULL;

    //  If input has not been set for an open file yet, try to open it.
    if (!input)
    {
        input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
        if (!input)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to open input.txt.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (int c = fgetc(input); c != EOF && c != '\n'; c = fgetc(input))
        putchar(c);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Note static objects should generally be avoided, as they complicate program state and so may lead to more bugs. It is okay to play with them in student programs to learn how they work, but their use in real-world applications should be limited.